# mysql/php increase number or insert not working

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, count

I have this code:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$results= mysql_query("SELECT number FROM words WHERE keyword='$q'") or 

die(mysql_error());;
if($results){
mysql_query("UPDATE words SET number = number + 1 WHERE keyword='$q'") or die(mysql_error());
}
else{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO words VALUES ('$q', '1', '$d')") or die(mysql_error());    
}
```

and i have the table `words`:

```
+--------+--------+-- -----+
|keyword |number  |date    |
+--------------------------+
|one     |1       |01-01-01|
+--------------------------+
```

When `$q` is `one` the number increases with 1
But when `$q` other word nothing happens. I want that when `$q` is not in keyword list, to be registered, and if `$q` is in the keyword column, number increases with 1. "If the word exists" works, but "if it doesn't" doesn't work....
please help! Thanks!

Comment: `$results` will only be false if there's an error that prevents the first query from running. Not finding any matching rows is not an error. Use `mysql_num_rows()` to find out how many rows were found.

Comment: Is there a unique index on the `keyword` field? If so, you can use `INSERT` with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` option.

Comment: Instead of `'$d'` you can use `NOW()`.

Comment: and if there wont be any rows matching, the $row_num will be 0?

Comment: yes it will be 0 and if the query failed it will be false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `keyword` is the primary key of the table, you can do it in one query:

```
INSERT INTO words (keyword, number, date)
VALUES ('$q', 1, '$d')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = number + 1
```

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin and i get this error when i try to make it primary key: `#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'keyword' used in key specification without a key length`

Comment: Don't use text, use varchar. There are restrictions on using indexes on text columns.

Comment: i made it varchar, but now it says: This is not a number

Comment: You have to specify a maximum size when defining a char or varchar column e.g. `varchar(32)`